# Linux Bash - Taking content out of a XML file

Tags: linux

So, I have used XPath before to take data from a XML sheet and print it out so that

Property1 - Property2 - Property3

are displayed like that. Now, I want to do the same in Linux Bash. I know how to use Linux Bash a little, and was able to get some of it to print out, but not like I needed it to.

Here is an example of how the XML sheet will look

```
<xml>
<content>
<items>
<item>
<name>I need this information</name>
<item>

<lists>
<list>
<name>I DONT need this information</name>
</list>
```

```
<hello>
<name> I need this information also</name>
<hello>
```

Notice that I have three instances of name so I cant simply use 
cat xmlfile | grep "name" 
since there is more than one place that has name

Thanks!

Comment: Is this XML really going to be malformed?

Comment: No, I have never used awk. I can look into it if you think it will make this doable.

Comment: @PolarisUser Re: "malformed", the content you gave is not valid XML; for instance, you're missing necessary closing tags. Is it representative, or you were simply being a bit sloppy in trying to write examples?

Comment: @PolarisUser: As in not a valid XML doc.  If it's valid XML then you *definitely* want to use a tool for handling XML (there are multiple tools that can execute XPath etc from a command line). Treating XML as a flat file is asking for trouble... but if it's malformed, these tools will most likely barf.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was just trying to give an example. I can go format it better. The XML file I have is formatted properly. Sorry about that.

Comment: Err. Adding a `<content>` opening tag without a matching closing tag makes this document further from being well-formed, not closer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) to execute your query as XPath.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t \
  -m //item/name  -v . \  # print first item name
  -o ' - ' \              # print intermediate dash
  -m //hello/name -v . \  # print second item
  -n                      # print trailing newline
```

Also, some very new versions of `xmllint` have a `--xpath` argument which can be used to run queries.

Comment: I will try this since I already know how to do it with XPath since I got it working in c#. Thanks!